# How can I simulate breaking loops in Minizinc?

Tags: minizinc

I have an array of variables called LIST. That can be indexed from 1 to tMax, and it can assume values from an enum called SYMB.

My objective is minimize the max distance between same occurrences of SYMB in LIST.

For example, if LIST = {S1, S2, S1, S3, S2, S1}.

S1: maximum distance is 3. The S1 in position 3 and S1 in position 6.

S2: maximum distance is 3. The S1 in position 2 and S1 in position 5.

S3: maximum distance is 0. It only has 1 occurrence of S3.

```
int: tMax;
enum SYMB;
array[1..tMax] of var SYMB: LIST;
var int: obj;

constraint forall(i in 1..tMax, j in i+1..tMax 
             where LIST[i] = LIST[j]) 
                       (obj = max( abs (i - j) , obj) );
solve minimize obj;
```

However, this code is considering the distance from the first occurrence of S1 in position 1, and last occurrence of S1 in position 6, so the distance is 5.

I would like to know if it is possible, and how to do, to check only the first occurrence between same SYMB. S1 from the index 1 compared with S1 from the index 3, and S1 from index 3 compared with S1 from index 6.

It's a kind of 'break' the internal loop after the first comparison.

Thank you all.

Comment: **1.** is there a fixed number of occurences for each SYMB in LIST?

Comment: Yes, it is a fixed number for each SYMB in LIST.

Comment: and what would that number be? is it the same for every SYMB?

Comment: There is an `array[SYMB] of int: COPIES`, this array stores the number of copies of each SYMB, this array is an input data.